# whitelisting html5 data-* on certain tags for CKeditor 4

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, wysiwyg, fckeditor

I've been trying to find a way to restrict data-* to certain tags in ckeditor4. As of now, I cant set it on any tags as it just strips them instantly.

I've tried adding it to the [whitelist plugin](http://ckeditor.com/forums/Plugins/Whitelist-elements-and-attributes) like this (edit the plugin file to add/remove them):

```
  CKEDITOR.config.whitelist_elements = {
    a: { attributes: {href:1, rel:1, title:1, data-*:1} }
  );
```

I've also tried using [allowedContent](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-allowedContent):

```
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    allowedContent: 'a[!href,rel,title,data-*]'
  });
```

Am I doing it wrong, or is there another way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: The Whitelist plugin is not related at all to the ACF in CKEditor 4.1 
It's basically a simple/stupid version of ACF that applies a very basic filtering, but it won't help you with any problem with ACF (on the other side it can cause you great confusion because then you have two separate filtering systems running at the same time)

Comment: I have tried running them one at a time, neither seems to work. Is there a better solution, or am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: I'm not sure about ACF (which is the way that you should go with CKEditor 4.1), but in the whitelist plugin there are no wildcards, so that ´data-*´ will match only an attributed named ´data-*´ not ´data-mine´.

Comment: (ACF does not support wildcards yet](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10202), but most likely we'll be able to implement this feature in 4.3 which is scheduled for the beginning of September. There is a [workaround](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10471#comment:1), but it's a little bit hacky.